# Как вывести данные в консоль с конструктора?

Tags: java, конструктор

Друзья, помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.
Есть такая задача:
Сделать класс Burger, который будет иметь поля булочка, мясо, сыр, зелень, майонез.
Сделать конструктор, который позволять делать обычный бургер (все компоненты).
!!!В конструктор добавить вывод в консоль состава данного варианта бургера (при создании экземпляра бургера использующего данный конструктор - будет выводиться в консоль его состав).

? Не могу понять, как печатать с конструктора. Код ниже ничего ничего не выводит.

```
 public class Burger {

    //INGREDIENTS:
    private String bun;
    private String meat;
    private String meatAdditional;
    private String cheese;
    private String greens;
    private String mayonnaise;

    //CLASSIC BURGER RECIPE:
    public Burger(String bun, String meat, String cheese, String greens, String mayonnaise) {
        this.bun = bun;
        this.meat = meat;
        this.cheese = cheese;
        this.greens = greens;
        this.mayonnaise = mayonnaise;

        System.out.println("Classic burger recipe: " + this.bun + "+" +  this.meat + "+"
                + this.cheese + "+" + this.greens + "+" + this.mayonnaise);
    }

      public static void main(String[] args) {

   }
}
```

Comment: Чтобы конструктор что-то напечатал, нужно вызвать этот конструктор. Обычно метод `main` это точка входа в приложение, вызовите из `main` ваш конструктор с нужными аргументами: `Burger burger = new Burger(...);`.

Comment: Я конечно все понимаю, но это вопрос даже не начального уровня

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Burger {

    //INGREDIENTS:
    private String bun;
    private String meat;
    private String meatAdditional;
    private String cheese;
    private String greens;
    private String mayonnaise;

    //CLASSIC BURGER RECIPE:
    public Burger(String bun, String meat, String cheese, String greens, String mayonnaise) {
        this.bun = bun;
        this.meat = meat;
        this.cheese = cheese;
        this.greens = greens;
        this.mayonnaise = mayonnaise;

        System.out.println("Classic burger recipe: " + this.bun + "+" +  this.meat + "+"
                + this.cheese + "+" + this.greens + "+" + this.mayonnaise);
    }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Burger burger = new Burger();
   }
}
```

Конструктор класса отрабатывать если этот класс создаётся, например:

```
Burger burger = new Burger();
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы написали код в конструкторе, но сам конструктор нигде не вызывается. Вызовите конструктор из метода `main` и запустите класс `Burger`:

```java
public class Burger {

    ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Burger burger = new Burger("", "", "", "", "");
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Так и сделаю. Думал, что можно прямо с конструктора печатать, не выходя за его пределы.